# Python append indicator to end of list

Tags: python-2.7

edit: becuase of the below comment about the XY effect. trying to simplify. I am wanting to store metadata about the particular line of a file if it contains a value. if that value does not exist i want to store a 0 so i know that the value does not exist. the file is located on a unix box. right now i am manually searching using the 'GREP -f file1 file2' command. I am trying to automate it with python.

I am trying to add to a dataset a indicator filed. the for loop loops through each line of a file and i want to add a bool value to the end of the list row if the value is found. also if there is a easier way to search a file then to read all lines then loop through them and use. it seems really ineffictive to loop through every line of a file multiple times

```
var in line
```

The data set is simple it looks like

```
[field1row1,field2row1,field3row1]
[field1row2,field2row2,field3row2]
```

then i loop through the file

```
with open(file,'r+') as f:
lines = f.readlines()
      for searchVal in dataset:
          for line in enumerate(lines):
                if searchVal[0] in line:
                      #Append line to end of row in dataset Field4
                else:
                      #append 0 to end of row in dataset Field4
```

Comment: I think [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) might be a good read for you.  I'd ask "what problem are you trying to solve"?  Are you trying to store metadata about a file to see if a certain value is present?  This problem can be solved in many ways

Comment: Ok thanks I will take a look